# How do you delete an unstoppable Windows Service from the list?

Tags: windows-7

Is it possible disable and then erase all references in registry to unstoppable process to get rid of it for good?

Comment: CLeaning up the registry would have to be manually done. No app would know what changes were made to registry except for the services that was installed. Unless you reinstall the service with a registry snapshot app running to compare before and afters. Use AutoRuns to stop the service...http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure that you are the only administrative entity logged in.  Unplug or disable networking to ensure that you aren't conflicting with domain-level crap.  Then there is the really easy way, the easy way, and the hard way.

Autoruns from sysinternals.com is the really easy way.

The easy way is to start a command line as an administrator.
  Run sc query  to confirm what you think
  run sc stop  to stop the service (it might not stop, but it might...)
  run sc delete  to remove the service--it will remove the settings from the registry.
  if you're super cautious, depending on what the service is, delete or rename the executable.
  If you weren't unable to stop the service.  Reboot.  If the service is not running, the really important question is why?

The hard way is to boot into safe mode command line mode and use sc and reg to stop, disable, and delete the service and associated files.

Caveat--you'd be surprised how easy it is to hork seemingly unrelated things.